# QGIS showing text annotations from other geographically adjacent projects

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have a few QGIS projects that are adjacent to each other, geographically, but I have them as seperated projects within QGIS.
Occasionally, text annotations from one project will appear in another where there's some overlap of the geographical location.
Sometimes they only show up in Print Composer but aren't in the main QGIS window when I go to delete them.

Comment: Pictures are a wonderful way of illustrating complex issues - e.g. the problem you're facing.

Comment: Erik, I'll try and take a screenshot when it next occurs. It's an intermitent issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The annotations made in one project appear in other projects, too. I'm always using the same location.