# Annotations from different and completely unrelated QGIS projects appear

Tags: qgis, annotation

Annotations from completely separate QGIS projects appear in unrelated projects, not all created or necessarily accessible by me. This question was asked around 6 months ago here, a different use case, but may make sense to merge (I am new here):

[QGIS showing text annotations from other geographically adjacent projects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377860/qgis-showing-text-annotations-from-other-geographically-adjacent-projects)

To elaborate a bit further, not all the annotations appear, just a few random ones. Once removed, annotations can come back - but I cannot see a consistent pattern. I don't think the annotations disappear from the originating project (which is a life saver obviously), if deleted from the offended project. We usually create a design label folder with separate point layers to attach the annotations to, but sometimes even these randomly detach themselves (user errors may explain this, of course).

The particular use case is that I work with a number of different people on NextCloud. We share a small number of project assets, but none that would necessarily explain this problem (as I don't have access to the projects with the offending annotations). In a recent project I was working on my own NextCloud instance, unrelated to my co-workers, and again the same issue surfaced ... the image below is self explanatory I think, and just for completeness the annotation belongs to a project I have no access to, have never loaded.

If it were up to me I would not use annotations!

[image: annotations from unrelate projects appear]

Comment: Not sure but the question you mentioned is for ArcGIS and you screen capture is QGIS !? There is no group in QGIS annotation (if yes, not aware)

Comment: That link got corrupted ... thanks for pointing that out! I'll correct that now.